# pandas fillna(0), when '0' is categorical

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data, fillna

Suppose I left-join `df2` onto `df1`(using some key `my_id`), where `df2` has a column `my_flag` containing values 0 and 1 as type categorical. After the join, those records of which `my_id` is present in `df1` but not in `df2` will have the value `nan` in the newly joined column `my_flag`. Appending `.fillna(0)` will give me *error: fill value must be in categories*

How can I fill the missing values with the categorical '0'?

Comment: Fill with `'0'`, not the integer `0` since the string `'0'` is one of your categories

Answer (score 0):

Use:-

```
df2['my_id']=df2['my_id'].astype('float')
df2['my_id']=df2['my_id'].fillna(0)
df2['my_id']=df2['my_id'].astype('int')
df2['my_id']=df2['my_id'].astype('category')
```

Note:- You are using old version of pandas in `pandas 1.2.2` this code: `df2['my_id'].fillna(0)` gives a warning and It works